# SOQL Aggregate expressions

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

This class is still work in progress, how to resolve the error from Line 8 - 'only root queries support aggregate expressions' does this mean AggregateResult can't access values inside a subquery?  This is a coding exercise to sum opportunity amounts at account level, or to simulate rollup summary feature.

```
public class ROI {

public static Decimal calcROI(List<Opportunity> oppsList) {
    
    for (Opportunity opp :oppsList) {
       
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults
            = [SELECT (Select SUM(Amount)sum FROM Opportunities) 
               From Account WHERE Id = :opp.AccountId 
               Group By Id];
        Object totalAmount = groupedResults[0].get('sum');
    }
        Decimal totalAmount = 100;
        Return totalAmount;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: why not just put a rollup summary field on Account that sums Opportunity.Amount; [see doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues here:

1. SOQL in a loop
2. Incorrect use of aggregation

Switch the processing round to remove the loop over the opportunities by using a query like:

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [
    SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) sumAmount FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN :oppsList
        GROUP BY AccountId
];

...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting means just that. Subqueries cannot contain aggregate functions (sum, count, max, avg, min). Only the main query (root query) can have those.

Beyond that, Phil W hits it pretty close to the head (get that query out of the loop).

The one point I'd like to make here is to call attention to your objective. You say you want to roll-up data from Opportunities to the associated accounts. Chances are pretty good that you're not going to be passing all of the Opportunities from all of the involved accounts (and almost certainly not all in a single call, especially if this is executed as part of a trigger).

Instead of basing your query around the Opportunities that you're given, you likely want to base you query *around the accounts that are involved*.

With that in mind, the usual gather-query-process approach applies.

- Loop over your given Opportunities, and extract the Account Id (put it in a list or a set)
- Run your query, it should have `FROM Opportunity`, group by `AccountId`, and add a filter in the `WHERE` clause to make sure that you fetch *all* Opportunities that point to *any* of the Account Ids that you gathered from the previous step
- Iterate over the results so you can pull out the `AccountId` and whatever fields you're aggregating (you don't need to query your accounts separately to be able to update them. The SObject constructor can set the record Id, e.g. `new Account(Id = <something>, otherField = <something else>);` and that's the big thing you need to be able to update records.

Comment: the line of accList.add is giving an error: